# Sort NSArray with a specific key

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I'm have requested an array from server and now I wanna filter all data which have `"status_read": 1` in an new array. How can I do it? This is my data response:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "message": "success",
  "data": [
    {
      "logo": "http://**.com/timepicker/images/default_o.jpg",
      "title": "Title 1",
      "icon": "https://**.com/admin/dashboard/dist/img/a.png",
      "type": 1,
      "link_detail": "",
      "id_call": 12,
      "status_read": 1
    },
    {
      "logo": "http://**.com/timepicker/images/default_go.jpg",
      "title": "Title 2",
      "icon": "https://**.com/admin/dashboard/dist/img/b.png",
      "type": 0,
      "link_detail": "http://google.com",
      "id_call": 0,
      "status_read": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is my code for filter array:

```
NSString *dictionaryKey = @"status_read";
NSInteger predicateValue = 1;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %i", dictionaryKey, predicateValue];
NSArray *filteredArr = [readNotif filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
generalArray = filteredArr;
[self.notifTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I've update my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *jsonStr = @"{\"status\":\"success\",\"message\":\"success\",\"data\":[{\"logo\":\"http://**.com/timepicker/images/default_o.jpg\",\"title\":\"Title 1\",\"icon\":\"https://**.com/admin/dashboard/dist/img/a.png\",\"type\":1,\"link_detail\":\"\",\"id_call\":12,\"status_read\":1},{\"logo\":\"http://**.com/timepicker/images/default_go.jpg\",\"title\":\"Title 2\",\"icon\":\"https://**.com/admin/dashboard/dist/img/b.png\",\"type\":0,\"link_detail\":\"http://google.com\",\"id_call\":0,\"status_read\":0}]}";

NSData *data = [jsonStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

//orignal array
NSArray *array = jsonDict[@"data"];
//create predicate to filter the array
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"status_read == 1"];

NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"Filtered Array: %@",filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *arr = [result_dic valueForKey:@"data"];    
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K == %@",@"status_read",@"1"];

NSArray *filteredArray = [arr filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"Filtered Array: %@",filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary *dic1 = @{@"status_read" : @1, @"title" : @"Title 1"};
NSDictionary *dic2 = @{@"status_read" : @0, @"title" : @"Title 0"};
NSDictionary *dic5 = @{@"status_read" : @5, @"title" : @"Title 5"};
NSDictionary *dic4 = @{@"status_read" : @4, @"title" : @"Title 4"};
NSArray *array = @[dic1, dic2, dic5, dic4];

NSArray *result = [array sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSDictionary *_Nonnull obj1, NSDictionary *  _Nonnull obj2) {
    NSInteger objValue1 = [obj1[@"status_read"] integerValue];
    NSInteger objValue2 = [obj2[@"status_read"] integerValue];
    if (objValue1 > objValue2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else if (objValue1 < objValue2) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
}];

NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

The array will not change.